# Как разделить регистрационную форму на 2 части

Tags: html, вёрстка

Есть большая регистрационная форма с более чем 20+ полями.Идея заключается в следующем, разделить ее на две формы, в 1 форму оставить обязательные поля, а во вторую добавлять уже второстепенные. Со стороны UX обе формы сделать по принципу падающего списка ( то есть, чтобы при нажатии выпадала целая форма и при таком же нажатии сворачивалась) 
Для простоты понимания добавлю пример макета.

Вопрос заключается в том,как это реализовать со стороны верстки? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]